# Is there any advantage of using localhost as testnet in Metamask?

Tags: metamask, dapps, testnets, ganache-cli

I am using Metamask with ganache to deploy my Dapp, i use localhost testnet depend on some tutorials i followed it but really i don't know if it has any advantages comparing with other testnets or no? what is the best testnet in my situation? i search a lot about that but i didn't found any comparison contain localhost testnet, it just between other testnets like: Rinkeby and Ropsten, etc.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost is better in the beginning stages of development when you need to rapidly change things. once you come closer to finalizing your project, especially if it integrates with other projects, connecting things on rinkeby or another distributed test net is the next step. this also makes it available to anyone connected to that testnet.